# React props not getting updated when used in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a really strange behaviour. I have the following code (super simple version):

```
const CanvasManager = () => {
  const [overlays, setOverlays] = useState([]);

  return <CanvasOverlay overlays={overlays} setOverlays={setOverlays} />
}



const CanvasOverlay = ({ overlays, setOverlays }) => {

  const [open,setOpen] = useState(false);

  // .. some code

  console.log(overlays) // First render: [], second render: [{id: 123}]

  const openEditOverlayDialog = id => {
    console.log(overlays) // First render: [], second render: []  <----- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    const overlayData = overlays.find(o => o._id === id);
    setOpen(overlayData ); // <--- THIS IS WORKING, SO CONTEXT SEAMS RIGHT
  };

  const editOverlays = () => {
    const newOverlays = [...overlays];
    newOverlays.push({id: 123});
    setOverlays(newOverlays);
  }

  return <Button title="Edit Overlay 123" onClick={() => openEditOverlayDialog(123)} />
}
```

The first component has a state with overlays for a HTML5 canvas. It returns a component which handles the actual overlay. I can add a overlay {id: 123} there and it is set as a new overlay. It then is given as a prop to the CanvasOverlay component. When I console.log this it shows in the first console log but not in the on within the "openEditOverlayDialog" function.

What am I missing?

Help is much appreciate. Thank you all!

Comment: so basically when you call `openEditOverlayDialog`, you see empty array?

Comment: Correct. But I see the array is not empty in the rendering of the component. Just when I call the function.

Comment: please show the complete CanvasOverlay component, or at least how `openEditOverlayDialog` is used

Comment: @thedude It is complicated and not easy to write. Basiclly it is the setup above. You suspect that it is not set because the context in which the function is called is wrong?

Comment: @thedude setOpen is working... And it is basiclly fromt he same component.

Comment: are you using `useCallback` or `useMemo` in this component?

Comment: @thedude No, I don't. But I found out what the problem was. I used the function in a component which had a JavaScript library that rendered the button. The problem was that the javascript library used the wrong context which was not updated. So the functions worked (because they were in the function when it was initialized) but the updates of the overlays were not saved in the context.

Thank you for the help. all good now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 const editOverlays = () => 
     setOverlays([...overlays, id: 123]);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.